# Refresh an Azure search index

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I've been exploring **Azure Search** recently as I'd like to use it in some of our apps. I've created an index, imported the data and have began querying the data using both the *Search Explorer* and the *REST* APIs. All well and good.

I changed the underlying data to test out the *fuzzy searching* capabilities. However, I was getting incorrect results as the data being returned was still the old data. I eventually found how I forcibly refresh the underlying data from the **Azure portal**, but is there a way to do this using a *REST* API, or to automate this in some way. I don't want to have to keep manually refreshing the **Azure Search Index** going forwards.

Comment: Can you please share How did you forcibly changed the underlying data

Comment: @redarismail Check out the answer from Mick (below) that I accepted as the correct answer - I used a scheduled indexer to automatically update the index

Comment: My issue is that the data in the index is not overwritten, For example, I have 25,000 documents in my index once I refer to the indexer, it doubles. I want to overwrite what is inside the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> An indexer normally runs once, immediately after it is created. You can run it again on demand using the portal, the REST API, or the .NET SDK. You can also configure an indexer **to run periodically on a schedule**.

Source data will change over time, and you want the Azure Cognitive Search indexers to automatically process the changed data. [Schedule indexers in Azure Cognitive Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-schedule-indexers), where you can set a custom interval (between 5 minutes and 24 hours).

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: When I refresh and run the indexer. my index will be filled with duplicate data. For example, I had 25,000 documents, now it is 50,000. How can I overwrite the index instate of update

Comment: I have a Cosmos DB database, and every day we remove the data and insert new data into the DB. Our Cognitive search is connected to the cosmos DB, and once I run the indexer it duplicates the index instead of overwriting it. How can I overwrite the index?

Comment: @redarismail i am facing same issue ! Did you find any solution for the same ?

Comment: @user3768478 - No, I am still doing it manually, it is painful, I have to manually remove and re-create the index each time. However, if you do not need to do it manually and your data is consistent write a .net app that removes an index and recreates it then refreshes the indexer. Maybe the Azure Durable function is an option